# Sending Character Through Bluetooth

Tags: android

I'm not really sure what the best way to word this is, but basically I want to be able to send a character from an Android phone to a bluetooth module plugged into an Arduino. I've got no problems with the Arduino end, but I'm having trouble with the Android bit.

So far all I have is a click event on an image, and when I click that image I want to send a character, for example, 1.

Here's my current code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class ToggleLightsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void imageClick(View view) 
    {  

    }
}
```

I should point out I am a beginner to Android, as you might have guessed!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what you found about this?

Answer (score 1):

Starting point for Android Bluetooth code is the ["Bluetooth Chat example"](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Bluetooth extends Activity{

    private static final String TAG = "THINBTCLIENT";
    private static final boolean D = true;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private static String address = "00:06:66:45:0E:93";
    private static final UUID MY_UUID =UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private OutputStream outStream = null;
    public InputStream ins=null;
    public static String status;
    static int count_speech=0; 
    static String ipadd="";
    static int count_ip=0;
    static String inst_data="";
    static char ret;
    static String Data="";
    static int count=0;
    Reading rd;
    static int ch;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

           // setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth);

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            status=extras.getString("status");
        //  Data=String.valueOf(a);

            if(extras !=null) 
            {
                show("Inside Bt Activity");

                Log.e(TAG, Data);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "the value is " + Data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

                if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) 
                {
                    finish();
                    return;
                }

                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable your BT and re-runprogram.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                    return;
                }

                BluetoothDevice device =mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

                try 
                {

                    btSocket =device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);

                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ON RESUME: Socket creation failed.", e);

                }
                try
                {
                    btSocket.connect();
                    Log.e(TAG, "ON RESUME: BT connection established, datatransfer link open.");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Blutooth_socket is created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
                 catch (Exception e) 
                 {              
                    try 
                    {
                        btSocket.close();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e2)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "ON RESUME: Unable to close socket duringconnection failure", e2);
                    }
                }
          if(status.equals("something"))  
          {
                try 
                {
                    char c='whatever character u want';
                    writeSucess(c);

                /*    outStream=btSocket.getOutputStream();
                    ins=btSocket.getInputStream();
                   // Thread.sleep(5000);
                    outStream.write(1);
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    outStream.write('2');
                    //rd=new Reading();
                    //new Thread(rd). start( );
                    //new Thread(Writing). start( );
                   */ 
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ON RESUME: Output stream creation failed.",e);
                }
```

thr=e thing which is commented in the try block above. create a method and use those lines forwriteSuccess

Comment: Please provide some explanation along with the code you posted.